# redirect from example.com/forum to example.ir/forum

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, forum

i'm going to redirect from

`www.example.com/forum` or `example.com/forum`

to

```
www.example.ir/forum
```

using htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.ir/forum$ [OR]        
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com/forum$ [OR]    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com/forum$     
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.ir/forum$1 [R=301,L]
```

i fail to do that and i always got:

`www.example.irforum` (without slash /) which is dead link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have posted could not possibly redirect to `www.example.irforum` (without slash). In fact, the code you have posted won't do anything (since none of the *conditions* will match). If you are seeing a redirect then it's possibly a previously cached (erroneous) redirect.

Assuming `example.com` and `example.ir` are pointing to the same place then try the following in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^forum(.*) http://www.example.ir/forum$1 [R=302,L]
```

The above rules are processed as follows:

1. Does the URL-path (less the directory prefix) of the request match the `RewriteRule` *pattern* `^forum(.*)`? If so, then continue...
2. Does the `HTTP_HOST` server variable match the *CondPattern*. ie. Is the `Host` header either `www.example.com` or `example.com`? If so, then continue...
3. Redirect the request to `http://www.example.ir/forum$1` - this is the `RewriteRule` *substitution*. `$1` refers to the captured group (first parenthesised subpattern) in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* - ie. whatever matches `(.*)`.

If `example.com` and `example.ir` point to different servers then you don't need the `RewriteCond` directive.

Test with 302 (temporary) redirects until you are sure it's working OK then change to 301 (permanent). Or, test with browser caching disabled.

The `HTTP_HOST` variable contains just the HTTP `Host` header. eg. `example.com`. This contains no path information. Use the `RewriteRule` *pattern* to match the URL-path.

Comment: Wow, it works like a charm, thank you very much
BTW, how can I learn the logic of mod-rewrite? to understand what you've provided?

Comment: A lot of trial & error, testing and questioning everything! :) The [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) are perhaps too concise in many areas, with few examples, however, they are an invaluable reference. Complex rewrites often involve complex regex, which the Apache docs don't cover at all. [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) is my goto resource for regex. [askapache.com](http://www.askapache.com/) is a great resource with loads of code snippets and raw examples but little explanation. I'll add more explanation to my answer...